# Minecraft: Shift + Click (/replaceitem)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a fill clock and in a command block I have this command:

```
/replaceitem entity @p slot.inventory.13 minecraft:spawn_egg
```

And in the 13 slot there comes up an egg.

What I want it to do is give me money when I take the egg (like cookie clicker). When I shift click to take the egg after ~2 clicks it won't come up anymore unless I put an item in slot #13

Hope you can help

Comment: Why a fill clock, ever heard about repeating command blocks

Comment: What do you mean with "Take the egg"

Comment: I am using **1.8** and by "Taking the egg" i mean shift + click on it